# How to open a file in Windows 7 in Windows XP that is running in VMware

Tags: vmware

I have VMware installed with Windows XP.

I have html files in my Windows 7.
Now I want to open them in XP that I run in VMware.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Shared Folders](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html).

Answer (score 1):

In Virtual Machine settings there will be a tab called options. Under that tab there will be an option called Shared Folders, click on Add, give the share a name, and tell Vmware the path.

Then load up the share in Windows Explorer in the VM XP